# Спавн префаба в одной рандомной точке на unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Напишите пожалуйста скрипт, который будет спавнить префаб рандомно в одной, из этих точек
[image: Напишите пожалуйста скрипт, который будет спавнить префаб рандомно в одной, из этих точек]

Comment: ошибся с сайтом, вместо тебя пишут код на биржах фриланса. Здесь помогают написать код если у тебя были попытки и что-то не получилось

Answer (score 1):

Ты новый участник stackoverflow, так что на первый раз простительно, но в будущем учти, что здесь помогают, а не пишут код за тебя.

Сам код:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Man : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] points; //массив с твоими точками

    private void Awake()
    {
        GameObject point = points[Random.Range(0, points.Length)];//берем случайную точку из массива
        transform.position = point.transform.position;//перемещаем
    }
}
```